# Having max of column repeat for each row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a table A ,

```
A

    user count
    a      4
    b      1
    c      3
    d      2
```

I want to write a query which returns each value of A along with max value of count,something like

```
user  maxCount
a        4
b        4
c        4
d        4
```

The way I am trying to achieve this is,

```
select user,max(count) as maxCount from A
```

The result which I get is :

```
user maxCount
a      4
```

Which is clearly not what I want.

I understand I could write multiple queries(i.e. 'select user from A' /'select max(count) from A') as this may seem redundant ,

but I think having it this way would be best for me as I don't want to call mysql multiple times and also I push the returned data as a single jsonObj to the front end , so it is easier to have a single table then combing two returned-tables into one  and than converting into json

Comment: perhaps a `group by` clause? using aggregate functions without one is usually NOT how you'll eventually end having to write the query.

Comment: `this may seem redundant` - having the same value in every row is redundant

Comment: can't  use group by as none of my actual column is unique ,the above is just an example to simplify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the max value on all rows:

```
SELECT user,
       (SELECT MAX(count) FROM yourTable) AS maxCount
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: won't this subquery run on every single row though?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select user,max(count) as maxCount from yourTable group by user
```

That will get your your max counts, and group them by whatever unique values are in the user column.

Comment: this would serve the purpose only if user is unique but it not in my case